# finding and stripping a symbol in PySpark RDD

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a bunch of Csv files that I'm loading into a PySpark RDD. They each have a double header which I've able to successfully remove after concatenating all the Csvs. The aim is to eventually have a nice clean Dataframe.

Theres a date time column in the original Csvs thats causing me issues however, here is what some of the values look like;

```
2017/02/15-9:54:
2017/02/15-9:56:
2017/02/15-9:58:
2017/02/15-10:00
2017/02/15-10:02
```

I want to be able to strip the ':' when it happens to be the last character or format to a proper datetime.

Heres what my data looks like :

```
u'2017/02/15-11:28,name,99.77341,1.5625,53,14.44655,53,1596.375,1.436081,0.4915466,0.1103516,9.31524,3.125,2.910973,4.6875,53,46,1596.375,5.380112', 
u'2017/02/16-7:48:,name,99.7734,4.6875,49,14.51247,49,1596.374,1.347595,0.4937897,0.1104431,9.318081,2.34375,2.90873,0,49,43,1596.374,5.213211,'
```

I've tired:

```
rdd2= rdd.map(lambda x: x.replace('%Y/%m/%d-\d{2}:\d{2}:' , '%Y/%m/%d-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'))

rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda x: x.rstrip(':'))
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `datetime` variable is the first column, you can do:

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0].rstrip('\:'), x[1:])).map(lambda x: (x[0],) + x[1])
```

Comment: that seems to work great, however when calling rdd.take() afterwards to only displays the datetime column in the rdd. Do I have to join that with the rest of my Rdd ?

Comment: I think I've solved the above by this

`rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda p:(p[0].rstrip('\:'), p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5], p[6], p[7], p[8], p[9], p[10], p[11], p[12], p[13], p[14], p[15], p[16], p[17], p[18]))`

Comment: Yes, that works. I also updated the answer with a shorter version where you dont need to specify all variables individually.